# JavaScript assets are fetched on each request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

I suspect the problem I'm about to describe is caused by Turbolinks, but I don't see how. I am using Rails 4, Turbolinks 3.0 and jquery.turbolinks. Suppose there is this CoffeeScript:

```
alertClicked = ->
  alert 'Clicked'

$ ->
  $(document).on 'click', '.foo', -> alertClicked()
```

When I first load the page and click on '.foo' I get one alert. If I visit a link and click on '.foo' again I now get two alerts. Another link visit leads to three alerts and so on. I suppose, Turbolinks is fetching the CoffeeScript assets on every request and they accumulate, so that the same scripts are executed multiple times. However, at least in Chrome, when I go to the Dev Tools -> Source I only see single copies of the files.

Does anyone has an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Try adding .off('click') before .on(

Comment: @DenizEng ok, so this works, but can you explain why? Isn't this just a workaround or is it exepcted behavior? Would it affect the other javascripts that act on other pages of the app? Thank you.

Comment: You were binding the event handler multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K., so as the [jquery.turbolinks README points out](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks#events-firing-twice-or-more):

> You should be binding your events outside a $(function()) block. This will ensure that your events will only ever be bound once.

Following this advice, my example would look like this:

```
alertClicked = ->
  alert 'Clicked'

$(document).on 'click', '.foo', -> alertClicked()
```

and everything works as expected.